# IIS Hosted RAD Server sending request to another server

Tags: delphi, iis

I have a rad server application hosted in IIS.

Client send requests to this rad server and server respond to it - all fine here.
but now, certain times, to cater the client's request, the rad server has to send request to another server. (for ex : jasper report server).

my problem is, when the client requests such a request, the rad server fails to execute the request to the jasper server, and in browser  when I test this request I get the response : Client : REST request failed: Error sending data: (12002). Ideally it should have downloaded a pdf and placed it in the documents folder. Such requests works perfectly when I run from RAD development server. But the RAD Server hosted in IIS fails to do this.

The endpoint is /GetReport which calls a function called DownloadReport (written in a datamodule) which will execute a TRestRequest.Execute which requests for the report from the jasper report server. But here, the .Execute wont just get executed at all no exception are thrown either inside DownloadReport method.

I turned off firewall in bother the systems. Is there something that I must configure in the RAD server application's INI so that the RAD server can communicate to another server ? or is there anything that I should configure in IIS ?

Can somebody help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Check the log files on the Jasper server. There's probably an error message in there that should lead you along...

Comment: Or if there's no entry in the log for the request from the RAD server, that'll tell you something as well (that the network route from the RAD server to the Jasper server should be investigated).

Comment: @HeartWare in the jasper logs there were no new entries and to check the route between the system where the rad server is installed and the jasper report server, i created a vcl app which calls the url to jasper report server - this worked. so i assume the request from the requester system to jasper report server goes well. Could there be something that needs to be checked inside IIS so that a request from hosted app goes to another sys ?

Comment: Error 12002 is ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT. Have you tried testing the request from the same user account that the RAD Server/IIS uses?

Comment: As @UweRaabe mentions, and with your test VCL App working out of the box, you should try your VCL program while logged into the same user as IIS. Or configure (temporarily) the IIS user to be the same as the user your VCL app is running under.

Comment: the rad server application was running in applicationpoolidentity and the vcl was on a local admin account. so this could be the problem rite ? i have to check how to run the rad server application with a high privileged user, i do not know how to do this at the moment.. i will update it here soon..

Comment: i ran the rad server app under administrator. still no luck

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this as follows :

The TRestRequest object which sends request to the Jasper Report Server should have its property SynchronizedEvents set to False. When ran from the RAD Development server, this property should be set to True.